# Installing package by adding package to node package managers package.json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure, npm

Sorry for such a trivial question, but I'm new to node.

So can one install a package using only the npms `package.json` file? If yes how can we achieve this? I know I could install it using `npm install packageName` command, but my project is running on windows azure mobile service and it just allows to modify the `package.json` file and not to run the `npm` commands.

So if this is possible, then where do I specify the package name to load and install in the `package.json` file?

Comment: you will get `dependencies` & `devDependencies` fields in package.json file, modify them accordingly.

Comment: @Mritunjay Do I add the package name to dependencies as array or what? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer See [the documentation](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/doc/files/package.json.md#dependencies) for syntax.

Comment: I've added how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using package.json, imagine you want to add package `express` as dependency:

```
{
  "name": "TAP",
  "description": "Simple package by TAP",
  "author": "The amateur programmer",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": ">= 1.2.0"
  }
}
```

After making changes to the `package.json`, you need to run `npm install` command for changes to take effect.
For more information, please refer to the [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/package.json.html#dependencies).

Comment: Will this load and install the package properly?

Comment: It will, but you have to run `npm install` once in that package folder, so that NPM checks `package.json` and installs lacking modules

Comment: I assume azures node does this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

you will get dependencies & devDependencies fields in package.json file, modify them accordingly.

Let's assume you have following content in `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "node-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0"
  }
```

If you want to add `underscore` as dependency modify `dependencies` add another key as `package-name`

```
 {
  "name": "node-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "underscore" : "~1.0"
  }
```

But make sure adding `,(commas)` properly.